# why my sqoop import is not working with hadoop encrypted password method?

Tags: sqoop

As per some requirement, I have used the hadoop security password encryption method to encrypt the password and use it with sqoop import. Below is the link that talks about the encryption method.

```
http://www.hadoopadmin.co.in/tag/hadoop-security-credential-provider-path/
```

However, when I am executing the below sqoop import:-

```
sqoop import -Dhadoop.security.credentials.provider.path=jceks://<hdfs path to file>/encrypt.jceks --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://IP:PORT/DB' -–username abd -–password-alias alias_pwd -–table Table_name --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table amitesh_db.hive_tbl --target-dir /<path>/hive_test -m 2
```

I am getting the following errors:-

```
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -–username
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: abd
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -–password-alias
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: alias_pwd
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -–table
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: Table_name 
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --hive-import
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --create-hive-table
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --hive-table
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: amitesh_db.hive_tbl 
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /<path>/hive_test
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -m
18/08/27 08:17:42 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 2
```

Looking at the nature of the error, I have tried all possible permutations combination of the sqoop switches, but none of them are working.

Can somebody help me figure out my mistake, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credentials provider api is not required in the sqoop invoke command. You just need to specify the password alias and it should work. Also keep this in mind you have to save the password alias before using it in sqoop. The hadoop credential provider api is available only after hadoop 2.6.